# Both men and female traits for characters

Tags: metaplex, sugar

I have both men and female traits for characters... but how do I generate men and female characters in a simple way?
Can I first generate females, then generate men after that, and then use a script that manages to blend the two collections with the JSON and PNGs correctly? Or does anyone have a better and faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Will depend on the generator that you will use, I recommend you to code your own generator to handle all the logic in order to create all the NFTs at once.

Other way is generating both in separate and then create a simple script to mix both generated files into one asset folder that follows the [assets requeriments that Sugar](https://docs.metaplex.com/developer-tools/sugar/guides/preparing-assets) ask for.